Application cannot be installed because of multiple FileProviders
I have 2 product flavors defined in my build.gradle and i created 2 different fileproviders for each flavor. It seems to cause conflicts when i install another app flavor on the device.
The error i get when trying to install:
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER Installation failed due to: 'Error code: 'INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER', message='INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Scanning Failed.: Can't install because provider name com.flavor2.app.fileprovider2 (in package com.flavor2.app) is already used by com.flavor1.app''

My providers in the manifest:
<provider
    android:authorities="com.flavor1.app.fileprovider1"
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/fileprovider1" />
</provider>

<provider
    android:authorities="com.flavor2.app.fileprovider2"
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/fileprovider2" />
</provider>


"I have 2 product flavors defined in my build.gradle and i created 2 different fileproviders for each flavor" -- this phrasing suggests that you have 4 total providers: 2 flavors, with 2 provider per flavor. That matches the error message. "My providers in the manifest" -- which manifest are you referring to? The one in main? One provider in the flavor1 manifest and one provider in the flavor2 manifest? Or something else?

@CommonsWare seems correct. are the two file providers shown above in the same Manifest of same flavour? if they are then, thats what the error says. you can have only one per app/flavour.

no. i have one manifest and defined 2 providers for 2 flavors.


i have one manifest and defined 2 providers for 2 flavors

That means if you were somehow to successfully install both apps, you would have four providers in total:



App
Flavor
Authorities




1
1
com.flavor1.app.fileprovider1 and com.flavor2.app.fileprovider2


2
2
com.flavor1.app.fileprovider1 and com.flavor2.app.fileprovider2



That will not work, as you cannot have two providers installed at the same time declaring the same authority.
What I presume that you want is:



App
Flavor
Authorities




1
1
com.flavor1.app.fileprovider1


2
2
com.flavor2.app.fileprovider2



IOW, the Flavor 1 app has the com.flavor1 authority, and the Flavor 2 app has the com.flavor2 authority.
To make that work, you need a total of three manifests:

One in your flavor1 source set, that contains the com.flavor1.app.fileprovider1 <provider> in an otherwise-empty <application>
One in your flavor2 source set, that contains the com.flavor2.app.fileprovider2 <provider> in an otherwise-empty <application>
One in your main source set, containing everything else

This sample project demonstrates having source sets with manifests, though in my case it is to have varying <queries> elements (which are children of <manifest>, so you will not see the empty <application> element).
